# JavaScript - Return promise AND/OR call callback?

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

I often see in other peoples docs something like:

> Callback is optional, if omitted returns a promise.

This is what I have:

```
export function doSomeAsync(options, callback) {

    const useCallback = (callback && typeof callback == 'function');

    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        // --- do async stuff here ---
        const check = (options.num === 1) ? true : false;
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (check) {
                finish(true, "Number is 1");
            } else {
                finish(false, new Error("Number is not 1"));
            }
        }, 1000);
        // ---------------------------

        function finish(ok, rtn) {
            if (useCallback) {
                if (ok) {
                    callback(null, rtn);
                } else {
                    callback(rtn, null);
                }
            } else {
                if (ok) {
                    resolve(rtn);
                } else {
                    reject(rtn);
                }
            }
        }

    });

    return (useCallback) ? false : promise;
}
```

The `finish()` function just avoids lots of `if...` statements scattered around.

I'm creating a promise object, whether or not I use it.

Testing like this:

```
doSomeAsync({ num: 1 }).then((result) => {
    console.log('p result', result);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log('p err', err);
});

doSomeAsync({ num: 1 }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('cb err', err);
    } else {
        console.log('cb result', result);
    }
});
```

This works, but I'm wondering if this is the best way, or if others have a better and more succinct implementation..?

Comment: Might be more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What promise library are you using? Bluebird even has [a dedicated function](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/ascallback.html) for this.

Comment: I'm running Node v4.2.2, with Babel for ES6 (`babel-preset-es2015 6.6.0`), but I haven't installed the specific babel ployfill for promises. So native Node promises I guess.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This could be simplified if you simply always used the promise, which you're always creating anyway:

```
export function doSomeAsync(options, callback) {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const check = (options.num === 1) ? true : false;
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (check) {
                resolve("Number is 1");
            } else {
                reject(new Error("Number is not 1"));
            }
        }, 1000);
    });

    if (callback && typeof callback == 'function') {
        promise.then(callback.bind(null, null), callback);
    }

    return promise;
}
```

Your function is always promise-based, also in the fact that it always returns a promise. The caller is simply free to ignore that. The callback argument is merely a "legacy fallback interface" (or "alternative interface" if you prefer) to using that promise.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the approach I was thinking.  Returning `false` seems a bit of a waste - also (being a .NET dev as well as JS) seems odd returning two different types from such a function.

Comment: Thanks deceze... I've updated my question with test calls. After updating to use your code I get: `p result Number is 1` and `cb err Number is 1`. Does the callback now only have one param?

Comment: @Stephen In my example above, the way the `promise.then` callbacks are bound, `callback` will receive one argument in case of success and two arguments (`false` and error) in case of failure. The callback is expected to have a signature of `function (result, err)`. Design that interface whichever way you like.

Comment: I notice the answer was updated with `promise.then(callback.bind(null, null), callback)` to produce the Node style `callback(err, result)` I was looking for. Thank you Bergi & deceze!

Answer (score 1):

You could get rid of all edge cases by always returning a promise, and define a default callback (a callback-shaped identity function) that handles the no-callback-supplied case:

```
const genericAsync = (stuff, callback = (e, i) => e || i) => new Promise(
  (resolve, reject) => doStuffWith(stuff, resolve, reject)
)
  .then(response => callback(null, response))
  .catch(callback);
```